# Unexpected value converting String date into epoch time?

Tags: java

The below gives: `1475020875000`. When I convert this epoch back to a human readable timestamp, I get: `Wed, 28 Sep 2016 00:01:15 GMT`, which is different from the initial date?

```
String date = "2016-09-27 20:01:15.0";
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
long epoch = df.parse(date).getTime();

System.out.println(epoch);
```

Comment: Because it was inputted using EDT but outputted using GMT.

Comment: Never do timestamp conversion without an explicit timezone.

Comment: That's a close race up there.

Answer (score 2):

You should specify Timezone for both input and output. You can use "z" to instantiate SimpleDateFormat and setTimeZone before using format method:

```
package stackoverflow;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class Programa {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        String date = "2016-09-27 20:01:15 GMT";
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z");
        long epoch = df.parse(date).getTime();

        System.out.println(epoch);

        Date d = new Date(epoch);
        df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
        String out = df.format(d);
        System.out.println(out);
    }

}
```

For available Timezones, try TimeZone.getAvailableIDs()

Answer (score 1):

Worked fine here:

```
package stackoverflow;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class Programa {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        String date = "2016-09-27 20:01:15.0";
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        long epoch = df.parse(date).getTime();

        System.out.println(epoch);

        Date d = new Date(epoch);
        String out = df.format(d);
        System.out.println(out);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You certainly forgot to consider the Timezone to use. If you do not define it, the default (from the JVM) is taken, and can for example differ depending on your server.

Answer (score 0):

Try `LocalDateTime`

```
    String date = "2016-09-27 20:01:15";
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    long epoch = df.parse(date).getTime();
    System.out.println(epoch);
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());
    LocalDateTime ld = LocalDateTime.parse(date, formatter);
    long epoch2 = ld.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant().toEpochMilli();
    System.out.println(epoch2);
    Instant in = Instant.ofEpochMilli(epoch2);
    LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(in, ZoneId.systemDefault());
    System.out.println(ldt);
```

output

```
1474986675000
1474986675000
2016-09-27T20:01:15
```